# How to login to the scot account after installing Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have successfully installed Oracle 11g R2 version. I don't have good knowledge about Oracle database. SQL developer needs a Database Connection.

[image]

I don't know how to create this. Searching through the Internet, I found [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130627030951/http://st-curriculum.oracle.com:80/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/sqldev_mngdb/sqldev_mngdb_otn.htm)

According to this site, there is HR user and HR database. Also there is some predefined tables. What are these tables and other things. Does Oracle comes with this default database?  Can't I create database with different name?  And how to create this database connection in right way?

These tables are not my creations

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you have not unlocked your `scott user account` while installation,please follow the steps below to unlock you scott account .

When you started installing oracle ,it asked for `global database name` and `database password` that password is used for the `sys system sysman dbsnmp account`.

1. SQL> conn user/password;

   SQL> conn scott/tiger;

Error message is displayed: the account is locked.

1. Try to login as `"system"`  - pass

   `SQL> conn  system/password;`
2. Unlock "scott"

   `SQL> alter user scott account unlock;`
3. Can change `"tiger"`:

   `SQL> alter user scott identified by tiger;`
4. SQL> conn scott/tiger;    -Success

`scott account` is locked in 11g due to security thinking,

Now you can type `Connection Name :ORCL` ,`username:Scott`,`password:tiger` to login

Comment: Thank you brother. you solve it. but still i have some problems about this table structure. what are these BONUS, DEPT, EMP tables ? does it default oracle tables ? i have add my table structure in my question. i don't create that tables. so what are they ? Please help me.

Comment: @Sha:These are not `default tables` because oracle creates these tables while installation .It will create `sample database` for you which contains these tables .So consider these tables as sample tables provided by oracle , and start developing for what you have installed 11g .:)

Comment: Thank you very much  Gaurav Soni :D